# Is an fsync-less tool such as eatmydata still relevant?

Tags: linux, performance

I've just heard about [eatmydata](https://www.flamingspork.com/projects/libeatmydata), which disables `fsync` to speed up things when data safety is not needed (tests, CI builds, etc):

> libeatmydata is a small LD_PRELOAD library designed to (transparently) disable fsync (and friends, like open(O_SYNC)). This has two side-effects: making software that writes data safely to disk a lot quicker and making this software no longer crash safe.

It's from 2007, but still [actively maintained on Github](https://github.com/stewartsmith/libeatmydata). However, not all distributions include it; Fedora, for instance, has a [nosync](https://src.fedoraproject.org/rpms/nosync) package, which is more or less equivalent (it does not include a wrapper command, but instead requires using `LD_PRELOAD`).

However, after trying it on several workloads, on different machines (one with a HDD, another with an SDD), on both Ubuntu and Fedora, the differences in execution times were negligible: about 5 seconds on a 2h task; 0.5s on a 2-minute task; etc. According to Google results, old-time users were reporting very large improvements in execution time.

Is there something that happened since then which rendered this "optimization" unnecessary? Are recent OSes smarter about handling `fsync`? Is there some easily testable workload in which large differences can still be observed?

Comment: I use it all the time during testing, compilation, video rendering and whenever I run Apt/Dpkg - the latter being essential!

Answer (score 2):

> when data safety is not needed (tests, CI builds, etc):

Tests and CI builds don't generally use explicit fsync much. As far as I've seen, the most common uses of eatmydata were situations where *every. single. file.* would get individually fsync'd before proceeding to the next one. Two examples of this would be the unpacking phase of `apt-get`, and various operations in SVN (such as `svnsync sync`).

> Are recent OSes smarter about handling fsync?

*Filesystems* might handle it differently, e.g. if I remember correctly, ext4 worked in a way that made individual-file fsyncs far more global than they would normally be (and the recently added ["fast commit"](https://lwn.net/Articles/842385/) feature is supposed to improve on that), while it might not be the case on, say, XFS.

Note here that "global" means that *other* jobs running on the same machine would also have an effect – e.g. log files being written, or just any recent task that produced a lot of writes that are still buffered, and trying to fsync() a single file ends up flushing those gigabytes of unrelated writes as well. That's something you wouldn't see when using a completely dedicated, idle system for your benchmarks...

Comment: Indeed, I forgot to check that: both systems where I tried it use ext4. I'll see if I can try it on a different FS, and see if that changes something.